# Slow boot after installing ubuntu 20.04 as dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bios

I have searched in this forum and others but all the questions are referring to Ubuntu specifically and I am not. In the first days it was ok, the OS choice appeared after 10-20 seconds, but now it takes more than 2-3 minutes (maybe more) to get to that choice. It takes fairly fast to boot up after ~can't complain~ but my concern is about the time before that. I am sure that there is a BIOS problem here, has it happened before to somebody else or it's just my laptop.(I have made a BIOS update and it also made it work for 2-3 than went back to being slow)

I have a Lenovo L340-15IRH
i5-9300HF
20 GB RAM

If you need any more details just comment I will be watching closely the feed.

system-analyze:
"Startup finished in 1min 32.781s (kernel) + 10.050s (userspace) = 1min 42.832s graphical.target reached after 10.036s in userspace"

Comment: Did you make any changes to partition(s) on your system?  ie. you caused a UUID to change, and thus the bootup is waiting for it to appear (as it used to, but can't anymore due to UUID change) until it eventually times out...  Did you look for reasons/clues in your boot logs etc? (`systemd-analyze blame` etc)

Comment: @guiverc what do you mean by changes to partitions? and how can I check for that also here is system-analyze:
"Startup finished in 1min 32.781s (kernel) + 10.050s (userspace) = 1min 42.832s 
graphical.target reached after 10.036s in userspace" I did not runned this before you said

Comment: Please don't provide additional detail via comment, edit your question & add it there (formatting options exist there, your detail is next to impossible when in comment so few will read it). By changing partitions, deleting, adding, formatting etc or any changes to the partition table (ie. your disk).  If it's a BIOS/uEFI issue, you're off-topic here, and I'd just test using other media (*live* for example rather than your hdd/ssd).

Comment: Well when I installed Ubuntu it asked me how much space I want to reserve for him and I chose about 30GB and I know it may be a BIOS/UEFI but do you know where I can ask BIOS related questions (forum or something else)? Also is "live" a software? I've searched but no conclusive results.

Comment: A *live* system is something like the Ubuntu install media (assuming you use a *live* ISO, not all ISOs are) and you select *Try Ubuntu*.  It boots from the initial media & runs in RAM, ie. no hdd/ssd is used thus any issues that exist on internal drives won't impact it. It allows you to evaluate other hardware components (including doing diagnostics on your hdd/ssd without them in-use at the time giving better results).

Comment: Yes I have that option on my USB stick, so i should boot up from my stick into the live version and run those commands that you mentioned?

Comment: I didn't really provide commands.. I would boot it up using *live* and compare speed (*live* if on a thumb-drive is usually slower than hdd or ssd, but it still provides some comparison). If it's a BIOS/uEFI issue as you suspect, it'll still be slow, meaning it's not a Ubuntu issue, but BIOS/uEFI and issue relates to your lenovo (or maybe a firmware setting). If *live* is comparatively *fast* then it could be a good indication is a Ubuntu setting (you'll be limited unless you're familiar with boot speed of *live* systems, maybe try on another *like* box for comparison if possible)